# Implementing rook movies in Javascript chess game

Tags: javascript, chess

I am trying to implement a chess game in javascript. I created a chessboard and a rook

```js
let board1 = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, "br", 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

//the following function creates a cheesboard:
function createBoard(board, boardEl) {
  board.forEach((row, i) => {
    row.forEach((col, j) => {
      const square = document.createElement("div");
      boardEl.appendChild(square);

      const piece = document.createElement("img");
      if (col) {
        piece.src = `pieces/${col}.png`;
        piece.style.userSelect = "none";

        piece.dataset.color = col[0];
        piece.dataset.symbol = col[1];
        piece.dataset.col = j;
        piece.dataset.row = i;

        square.appendChild(piece);
      }

      square.style.display = "flex";
      square.style.alignItems = "center";
      square.style.justifyContent = "center";
      square.style.userSelect = "none";

      square.dataset.row = i;
      square.dataset.col = j;

      if (i % 2 == j % 2) square.style.backgroundColor =   "green";
      else square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<body
    style="
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: white;
      overflow:hidden;
    "
  >
    <div
      class="board"
      style="
        width: 560px;
        height: 560px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
        border: 1px solid white;
      "
    ></div>
  </body>
```

and the following event Listeners are responsible for dragging the piece in the chessboard

```js
let draggedPiece;
let currentPiece;

document.addEventListener("dragstart", function (event) {
  draggedPiece = event.target;
  const { row, col, color, symbol } = draggedPiece.dataset;
  currentPiece = new Piece(row, col, color, symbol);
  console.log(currentPiece);
});

document.addEventListener("drop", function (event) {
  if (
    currentPiece.possibleMoves.find(
      (square) =>
        square.row == event.target.dataset.row &&
        square.col == event.target.dataset.col
    )
  ) {
    draggedPiece.parentNode.removeChild(draggedPiece);
    event.target.appendChild(draggedPiece);

    currentPiece.updateCoords(
      event.target.dataset.row,
      event.target.dataset.col
    );
    currentPiece.getPossibleMoves();
  }
});

document.addEventListener("dragover", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

in the drop eventListener I am check if the piece can move to the square that we want to drop to;
but when I update the the coords of the current piece they don't change. By the way here is The piece class:

```js
class Piece {
  constructor(row, col, color, symbol) {
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;
    this.color = color;
    this.symbol = symbol;
    this.possibleMoves = [];
    this.getPossibleMoves();
  }

  getPossibleMoves() {
    this.possibleMoves = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      if (i != this.col) {
        this.possibleMoves.push({ row: i, col: Number(this.col) });
        this.possibleMoves.push({ row: Number(this.row), col: i });
      }
    }
  }

  updateCoords(row, col){
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;
  }
}
```

Can you find some improvement on my code and help me solve this problem. Thank You.
Note: can you provide some hints, guidances and reference to help me in the creation of this nice game, And I don't know if the image will display when you run the code.

Comment: This may be ahead of what you need but from an OOP perspective, a chess piece should know it's own location and legal destinations before it's even picked up.  And this information should be updated after an opponents move. Just some things to think about.

Comment: If you see the class it has the possible moves attributes Which show where the piece can move.

Comment: Your coordinates are not being updated possibly because you create a new Piece on every drag event. I'll make a post with some other musings.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68976802/how-do-i-optimize-my-javascript-code-that-i-currently-have/68977984#68977984 for an alternative to board representation and move generation.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other things to consider while programming:

At the least you should have more classes: Board, Square, base class Piece from which you derive Rook, Bishop, Knight, etc...

1. Boards:

   1. How a Board is represented internally (maybe as a 1 dimensional array) has no bearing on how it's drawn (2 dimensionally). Let the html and css worry about that.
   2. Boards draw Squares.
2. Squares

   1. Have a fixed location on a Board
   2. Squares draw Pieces.
3. Pieces

   1. know their current Square
   2. All Pieces move But derived Pieces determine how
4. Rooks, Knights, etc (derived Pieces)

   1. Know their own legal moves. eg: a Rook cannot move through an occupied Square.
   2. Can draw themselves (.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could have piece classes for each piece instead of one piece class. Although you don't necessarily need separate classes for each piece type, you could get away with three:

1. Pawns,
2. Jumping pieces (kings and knights), and
3. Sliding pieces (rooks, bishops, and queens)

The move generation breaks down nicely in that way. Pawn movement is completely unique to pawns plus you have to handle move generation for double pushes from their starting rank, en passant, and promotions. Kings and knights move in the exact same way, they just target different squares. Similarly, rooks, bishops, and queens all move in the same basic way, just in different directions.

This way a king is created by injecting a king attack map into a jumping piece class, while a knight is created by injecting a knight attack map into the same class.

From an OOP perspective, it seems natural that a piece should keep track of where it is, however in practice this doesn't work very well (In general, OOP isn't the best way to approach chess programming, but it can work). In order to generate moves for a piece, you need to know both where the piece is, and where all the other pieces are. So can pick one of three options either:

1. the piece knows where it is and doesn't know how it moves, i.e., you have a separate class that contains movement rules for all pieces and applies it by extracting position information from piece classes, or
2. the piece knows where it is and how it moves, which would require very complex relationships in communicating positions between the various piece classes, or
3. the piece knows how it moves but not where it is, and position information is fed in from outside.

For option one, it doesn't really make sense to have a class that only knows where the piece is, there are better ways to store this information if that is all the class is doing. Option two, as described above, becomes very clunky and convoluted whenever I have tried to implement it. So, I think that option three is the best. The board knows where the pieces are, and the piece classes do not represent the pieces themselves, but instead represent the movement rules for those pieces.

I think it makes more sense to have a board class that tracks the pieces, piece classes that hold movement rules, and a move generator class that holds the rules for each piece. When the move generator wants to generate moves for a particular piece it can look at the board and see where the pieces of that type are (as well as other required information such as empty squares, opponent pieces, ep target, and castling rights) then reaches to its shelf of rule books (piece classes) gets the movement rules for the required piece and feeds in the information it obtained from the board.

The downside here is that you have piece classes that contain no data at all, just methods that implement the rules. So you would have to ask yourself if maybe they are better implemented as functions. Although, the class option does give you the option of run time polymorphism in rule generation, which you may find beneficial.

In terms of board representation, a good option, to begin with, are bitboards (which you can read about [here](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Bitboards)). I don't know much Javascript and don't know about how bit twiddling works for Javascript. However, even if you are not comfortable with using a single integer to represent a particular view of the entire board you could do something similar with a 64-element array of 0s and 1s.